Can I write OpenCL kernels using some kind of C++, to run on NVIDIA GPUs, in 2024?
OpenCL has had a bumpy ride over the years w.r.t. to the prospects of using C++ to write kernels. First there was "OpenCL C++ kernel language", standardized with OpenCL v2.1 - but that did not quite catch, and AFAICR never got supported on NVIDIA GPUs; and then, with OpenCL 3.0 - that was scratched entirely, in favor of C++ for OpenCL, which is "based on a Clang/LLVM compiler which implements a subset of C++17 and SPIR-V intermediate code" - and was announced/published as late as 2021.
Anyway, let's consider where we stand now, i.e. December 2024. Can I use one or the other of the C++-ish kernel languages, and compile it - using NVIDIA's own tools and libraries or even clang/LLVM and then NVIDIA stuff, so that it can run on NVIDIA GPUs? And if so - how, roughyl, is that done?
From what I gather, it should be something like:

C++-for-OpenCL source code 
==[A compiler such as clang which supports C++-for-OpenCL]==>
An intermediate representation, e.g. SPIR-V or PTX
==[One or more facilities by NVIDIA]==> 
kernel running on the GPU

but I'm not sure even about that, nor do I know how to make it concrete and specific.
Notes:

I am not interested in alternative ways to get GPUs to run stuff written in C++, e.g. using CUDA kernels, NVIDIA's thrust, SYCL, OpenMP, OpenACC etc. Those are all fine and good but not what this question is about.
I asked a similar question in 2019, when the state of affairs was different than today, and got an answer relevant to that time. I think this separate question is appropriate (but others may think differently).
If I could get PTX from C++-from-OpenCL, I know the rest of the way, so if you know how to make that step, I can fill in the rest of the answer: Basically, you load the PTX into memory and use cuModuleLoad().


Yeah, I already deleted my comment. Mostly because I'm confused what you actually want. Can you use OpenCL-3.0? Yes (I guess). But you want a C++ version … which isn't what OpenCL provides. But you also don't want any other tool or compiler extension like OpenMP. So … are you asking for a way to compile C++ kernels into SPIR-V and then execute that on CUDA hardware?

@Homer512: 1. NVIDIA hardware, CUDA is the software ecosystem name. 2. Basically, yes, although I don't really mind if SPIR-V is the intermediate representation; if I could compile .clcpp files into CUDA PTX or cubin code I would be quite happy.
